# ls command on a Synology NAS via SSH returns "ls: cannot read symbolic link"

Tags: linux, ssh, nas, synology-diskstation, ransomware

DISCLAIMER: I know nearly nothing of unix based things, shell etc...

A month ago a ransomware (0xxx) infected my Synology NAS. I contacted an expert to know if there's anything I can do. He told me to send him a dwlist.txt file containing all files and directories and he gave me this command: `ls -laR / > dwlist.txt`, so I opened the terminal on my Mac and I ran these commands:

```
ssh admin@NAS_IP
sudo -i
ls -laR / > dwlist.txt
```

and it returned a list of

```
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/10/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/10/task/10/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/11/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/11/task/11/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1104/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1104/task/1104/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1105/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1105/task/1105/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1106/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1106/task/1106/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/12/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/12/task/12/exe: No such file or directory
...etc
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

/proc is a virtual filesystem that shows you information about running processes

https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

If you look at the /proc folder you will see they all have a size zero:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 7 root   root      0 Aug 23 08:53 1
```

When you are reading from or writing to these files you're actually interacting with the Linux kernel.

In your case ls probably briefly saw a running process which was already closed when ls tried to get the "file" information.

Comment: So what can I do? It's not generating the file I requested

Comment: These errors do not indicate the file wasn't created, just that some files couldn't be read by ls. Even a single successful file read will generate a file. The file should be in your current folder, check with " ls -lah ". By default for root the folder is /root. Note that this is not visible in the synology web interface, you need to move it one of your volumes first " mv /root/dwlist.txt /volume1/example/folder1/ "